# CI controller url permalink

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've got a project in codeigniter and i want to modify its url link.

The current link is: [http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/647/bikearena.ro?/health_check/report/647/bikearena.ro](http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/index.php?/health_check/raport/578/)

And i want to remove "`health_check/raport/`" while the page is still working.

So the new url must look like: http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/647/bikearena.ro

I used some htaccess code for redirect and rewrite url but it doesnt work. So the current htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Please, dont bother with htaccess, its only a rule to remove index.php and any other rules wont work.

I just need to know from controllers how to do that.

Is it possible?

**EDIT for PACIO**

this is located in `health_check.php`

```
class health_check extends Home
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($base_site="")
    {
      $this->raport();
    }

    public function raport($id=0,$domain="")
    {
```

Comment: What's the name of the controller and method for that page?

Comment: The controller its health_check.php

Comment: @Pacio check the updated question please, i have included the answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of routes for this. Something like this:

```
$route['(:num)'] = 'health_check/raport/$1';
```

Comment: will it work $route['(:num)/(:any)'] = 'health_check/raport/$1/$2'; if i have anything else after the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can define routes for controller url permalink

Comment: Yeah, and the rules? I have no knowledge of doing this... Also, setting routes for controller will redirect my permalink in url browser?